# How to store weight values and converting to standard/metric weights?

Tags: javascript, converters

I'm working on a Vue application, and one of the features deals with weight values. I'm currently storing them in my database as grams, and then converting them to pounds. Eventually I'd like to be able to have the user choose between metric and standard computations. I've created a function that returns four calculations, however they don't seem to add up correctly.

```
export const convertToPounds = weight => {
  return (Math.round((weight / 453.592) * 10) / 10).toFixed(2);
};
```

This function is run four times. Once for the total, and three times based on which category the items filter into.

```
Total - 4170 grams converts to 9.20 lbs
ValueA - 2700 grams converts to 6.00 lbs
ValueB - 1400 grams converts to 3.10 lbs
ValueC - 70 grams converts to 0.20 lbs
```

Looking at the final conversions though, the three values add up to 9.30 rather than the 9.20 that should be returned.

My question is whether the conversion method is too inaccurate to handle these types of conversions? Or is storing weights in grams not the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are first Rounding it and then doing toFixed(2) which further rounds it. I checked briefly on google and it appears correct calculation: https://www.google.com/search?q=4170+grams+to+pounds

```js
const convertToPounds = weight => {
  return (weight / 453.592).toFixed(2);
};

// Total - 4170 grams converts to 9.20 lbs
console.log(convertToPounds(4170));
// ValueA - 2700 grams converts to 6.00 lbs
console.log(convertToPounds(2700));
// ValueB - 1400 grams converts to 3.10 lbs
console.log(convertToPounds(1400));
// ValueC - 70 grams converts to 0.20 lbs
console.log(convertToPounds(70));
```

Comment: I believe that fixes it, thank you! This is where my javascript noob-ness really shows, it should've been obvious that `Math.round` was the culprit. I think I'd found the function somewhere awhile back and at the time it appeared to work until I really started using it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To long fo a comment:

Exact numbers like `9.20`are not possible. They are binary rounded to the nearest possible number, here to `9.19999999999999929`. That's the reason, that `toFixed()` returns a string and not a number.

Also functions or expressions provided as answers here do not help:

```
value = Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
```

If you proof the result by `console.log(value.toPrecision(18))` you see, that the functions fails. All rounding functions, that returns a number will fail.

Why `toPrecision(18)`? Floating numbers are usually implemented as IEEE 754. JavaScript uses `double floats` with about 16 decimal digits. So 18 digits are a very exact decimal representation of the internal number.

Final note: Use `toFixed()` only for the final printing.

Comment: Interesting, this is a part of mathematics/ javascript/ whatever you want to call it, that I'm just very unfamiliar with. Why though would it matter whether I do the `toFixed()` during the calculation or inside of the UI? It seems like it would result in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are rounding. Why are you rounding? Is it so that the UI will not show a long decimal? If so, you should consider rounding at the UI level. Rounding at the data level like that is dangerous, since as you have found out; things will not add up internally and if you use the result of that in *another computation* then it will drift and become more inaccurate.

Consider a filter to do this, like one this gist (https://gist.github.com/belsrc/672b75d1f89a9a5c192c#file-gistfile1-js-L92):

```
Vue.filter('round', function(value, decimals) {
  if(!value) {
    value = 0;
  }

  if(!decimals) {
    decimals = 0;
  }

  value = Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return value;
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I'm rounding. I will give that filter a shot, thanks!